# I uploaded my php aplication using Filezilla and when I checked it online, all of the images are missing

Tags: php, database

I uploaded my php application using Filezilla and when I checked it online, all of the images are missing and total site get break. I don't understand this because everything works fine offline but when I check through after publishing it online, all the images disapear. I also checked all my links and they're fine.

Comment: Can you show us the php file?

Comment: Clearly your links aren't fine, or the images wouldn't be missing. There is not enough information here for anyone to help you.

Comment: Is your files name are lowercase?

Comment: @elliott Frisch : If my links are not fine, my project can't work offline and one thing i tried on another computer offline its good the problem is when I upload on server I  find my site is breaking and not showing images

Comment: @adam : I check my all file name they are in lowercase. and in code same lowercase is used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to open the images directly. Check the `.htaccess` permissions for the images.
2. If the images are displayed directly, check the links. Open the source of the page directly in browser and try to click the image links.